# Recursively find files that have a percentage of lines in common

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, grep, terminal, find

Is possible to recursively find files that have a percentage of lines in common?

I want an output where I have only files that are 50% the same of others or have 20+ lines in common.

I'm trying to isolate common functions in `*.java` files.

Comment: You might need a closer definition: you want *couples* of files with common lines? What if a file has common lines with multiple other files? Also, files may have common lines, but different numbers of lines. 50% of both, of one?

Comment: The list of files with some similarities in a Consequently way.

Comment: What does "a Consequently way" mean? Should it compare all files with each other, or does it only compare files with the same name in two hierarchies?

Comment: If there are lots of files, comparing every file with each other will be pretty expensive.

Comment: Comparing every file with each other. 200/300 *.java files

Comment: Do you have a tarball with files that we can download and play around with?

Comment: Okk Jedi! I will add an example tarball today and the output that I should get. Thank you

Comment: @devin, don't leave us hanging :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have 200-300 files, that is a lot of comparisons.  Supposing that was 200 files, then you would have

```
200 * 199 / 2
```

or 19900 comparisons (see *[How do I get the total number of unique pairs of a set in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859430/how-do-i-get-the-total-number-of-unique-pairs-of-a-set-in-the-database)*).

Besides handling the number of combinations, you need a way to measure the number of common lines.  You *could* use an approach like `diffstat` and count the number of added- and deleted-lines, e.g., in a shell script, and treat that as *change*, subtract it from the filesize to get *unchanged* lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
change=$(diff "$1" "$2" | grep '^[<>]' | wc -l)
change=$(expr $change / 2)
size1=$(wc -l "$1"| awk '{print $1;}')
size2=$(wc -l "$2"| awk '{print $1;}')
unchanged1=$(expr $size1 - $change)
unchanged2=$(expr $size2 - $change)
[ $unchanged1 -gt 20 ] && echo "$unchanged1 unchanged lines in $1 vs $2"
```

In this example, I computed but did not use the `unchanged2` value (the numbers need not be the same, and cluttering up the report may make it less readable).

But this is just to illustrate the approach: managing the 20 thousand comparisons will keep you busy.  For instance, you may make the example script produce results formatted as a CSV file:

```
[ $unchanged1 -gt 20 ] && echo "$unchanged1,\"$1\",\"$2\""
[ $unchanged2 -gt 20 ] && echo "$unchanged2,\"$2\",\"$1\""
```

and (calling it `compare-files`), use that like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "CHANGES,FILE1,FILE2" >report.csv
for file1 in *
do
    echo "comparing $file1" >&2
    for file2 in *
    do
        compare-files "$file1" "$file2" >>report.csv
    done
done
```

Comment: Simpler than piping `wc` to `awk` is:  `$(wc -l < "$1")`, instead of starting with *$added* and *$deleted*, why not `change=$(diff "$1" "$2" | grep '^[><]')`?